# Spring boot: FactoryBean<RestTemplate> jwt token headers initialized

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'd like to create a `FactoryBean<RestTemplate>` in order to avoid to create a `RestTemplate` each time a component, bean, service... requires it.

I mean, I need to inject a `ResTemplate` which it's already configured with `Authorization` header.

Up to now, I've been able to to create it, but I don't quite figure out what I need to write inside `afterPropertiesSet`:

```
@Component
public class RestTemplateFactory
  implements FactoryBean<RestTemplate>, InitializingBean {

    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public RestTemplate getObject() {
        return restTemplate;
    }

    public Class<RestTemplate> getObjectType() {
        return RestTemplate.class;
    }

    public boolean isSingleton() {
        return true;
    }

    public void afterPropertiesSet() {
        //???
    }
}
```

Also, I've implemented a service engaged to update current jwt token. Basiclly:

```
@Service
public class JWTService {

    private String jwt;

    public String getJwt() {
        return jwt;
    }

    //JWT handling related code
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can't you inject a `RestTemplate` into your `JWTService` and inject the `JWTService` whereever you need it?

Comment: According to your approach, the problem is that other project components, beans... will have to inject a `JWTService` instead of well known `RestTemplate` component. In the future, I'm going to be able to change a `JWTService` by a `BasicService`. Do you get me?

Comment: You are probably using `JWTService` or `BasicService` to "talk" to some external system. Why not create an `ExternalSystemService` or `ExternalSystemGateway` interface with an implementation that injects a `RestTemplate`? That way, other project components don't even need to know that `RestTemplate` is used to talk to the external system.